# from statement based on table name got from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables:

```
table1 
-id 1
-name animals

animals
-id 1
-age 13
```

Now I want to create sql statement something like this:

```
select age from (select name from table1 where id = 1)
```

It is posible to do this in ms sql ?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bad design.  I'd use a key to tie just two tables together:

**Categories**

```
 ID    Type
 1     Animal
 2     Person
 3     Building
```

**Things**

```
 ID    Type      Name                   Age
 1     Animal    Fluffy                 13
 2     Person    Joe                    23
 3     Animal    Lucy                   3
 4     Building  Empire State Building  80
```

The your query would be:

```
select age
from categories c
    inner join things t on c.Type = t.Type
where c.ID = 1
```

Add an index on the FK (join) column in **Things** to make this fast.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only using dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select age from ' + name from table1 where id=1    
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that this is not a good idea in general, and you'd be much better off changing your design as per [tvanfosson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272506/from-statement-based-on-table-name-got-from-another-table/5272603#5272603).

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want it:

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T2.AGE 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
INNER JOIN ANIMALS T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE ID=1
```